# meetup api DATE error

Tags: rest, datetime, meetup

I got a problem with the v3 of api meetup.com

Trying to request the api:

```
GET https://api.meetup.com/find/upcoming_events?sign=true&key=VALID-API-KEY&lon=32.97&page=1000&lat=4.95&page=20&offset=0&end_date_range=2018-07-19424:00:00
```

Expected behavior:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "end_time_range_error",
      "message": "end_time_range is not a valid time",
      "field": "end_time_range"
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual behavior:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 success
{
  [...]
}
```

From the docs:

> end_date_range: Return events that start before this date. The date
>   must follow this format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

https://www.meetup.com/de-DE/meetup_api/docs/find/upcoming_events/?uri=%2Fmeetup_api%2Fdocs%2Ffind%2Fupcoming_events%2F

So it is all about:

from the docs: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
from my request: 2018-07-19424:00:00

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, it's not too late for an answer to this question. If so, maybe this would be helpful for somebody else.
The correct format for this one is 2018-07-19T16:00:00